# Is there a server-wide scope CDI producer?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

Can I create a CDI Producer that is visible across all web applications deployed in the same server (e.g same jvm)? What would be a the scope for it? ApplicationScoped producers are visible only within the web app, so I need something more global that lives/dies with the server launch/stop. I am trying to avoid developing a JCA resource adapter (which would work, but is too rusty and cumbersome, with lots of XML) and stay within CDI only. Thanks!

Comment: You can have a producer visible across all deployments if you place it in some kind of static module which all deployments see. But I guess what you are *really* after is a scope which will be shared amongst all applications, it that correct? If that's the case, then the answer is - write your own scope. There is no built-in scope which would operate like this.

Comment: Thanks, I ma coming to the same conclusion and might end up writing a JCA adapter instead